# How to refactor react component separate for rendering and logic?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, module, react-redux, refactoring

I have react component:

```
    function FavoritesListItem({ merchant, config, isFavorited }) {
  const {
    name, id, logoUrls = {}, offersCount, rebate, showRebate,
  } = merchant;
  const { rebateOptions } = config;

  return (
  const renderActiveMerchant = () => (
    <div
      className="mn_favoriteMerchant"
      data-merchant-id={id}
      data-merchant-name={name}
      role="listitem"
      data-test="favorite-merchant"
    >
      <div className="mn_favoriteMerchantInner">
        <MerchantExperienceLink
          className="mn_favoriteMerchantLink"
          merchant={merchant}
          title={`Opens merchant detail page at ${name}`}
        >
          <FavoriteIcon
            merchantId={id}
            merchantName={name}
            labelUnfavorite={`Remove ${name} from Favorites list`}
            showSpinner={!isFavorited}
          />
          <div className="mn_logo"><img data-test="favorited-merchant-logo" src={logoUrls._120x60} alt={name} /></div>
          <p className="mn_offersCount" data-test="favorited-merchant-offers-count">{offersCount} offers available </p>
        </MerchantExperienceLink>
        {rebate && (
          <MerchantClickUrlLink className="mn_favoriteMerchantRebateLink" merchant={merchant}>
            <div className="mn_rebate">
              {showRebate
              ? <MerchantRebate {...rebate} {...rebateOptions} />
              : <MerchantNoRebateLabel />}
                ? <MerchantRebate {...rebate} {...rebateOptions} />
                : <MerchantNoRebateLabel />}
            </div>
          </MerchantClickUrlLink>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  const renderDeactivatedMerchant = () => (
     <div
      className="mn_favoriteMerchant"
      data-merchant-id={id}
      data-merchant-name={name}
      role="listitem"
      data-test="favorite-merchant"
    >
      <div className="mn_favoriteMerchantInner">
        <MerchantExperienceLink
          className="mn_favoriteMerchantLink"
          merchant={merchant}
          title={`Opens merchant detail page at ${name}`}
        >
          <FavoriteIcon
            merchantId={id}
            merchantName={name}
            labelUnfavorite={`Remove ${name} from Favorites list`}
            showSpinner={!isFavorited}
          />
          <div className="mn_logo mn_noRebateMerchantLogo">
            <img data-test="favorited-merchant-logo" src={logoUrls._120x60} alt={name} />
          </div>
          {rebate && (
            <div className="mn_rebate mn_deactivatedRebate">
              {
                showRebate
                ? <MerchantNoRebateLabel />
                : <MerchantRebate {...rebate} />
              }
            </div>
        )}
        </MerchantExperienceLink>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  return (
    merchant.type === 'Deactivated Merchant' ? renderDeactivatedMerchant() : renderActiveMerchant()
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = () => {
  const selectFavoriteByMerchantId = makeSelectFavoriteByMerchantId();
  return (state, { merchant }) => ({
    isFavorited: selectFavoriteByMerchantId(state, merchant.id),
  });
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(FavoritesListItem);
```

and need to refactor it to 2 separate components which will be just render renderDeactivatedMerchant and renderActiveMerchant. All other logic should be in this component FavoritesListItem
So I created components this way:

```
    export class FavoritesListItemDeactivatedMerchant extends Component ({ merchant, config, isFavorited }) {
  render() {
      const { merchant, config, isFavorited } = this.props;
      const {
        name, id, logoUrls = {}, rebate, showRebate,
      } = merchant;
      const { rebateOptions } = config;

      return (
        <div
          className="mn_favoriteMerchant"
          data-merchant-id={id}
          data-merchant-name={name}
          role="listitem"
          data-test="favorite-merchant"
        >
          <div className="mn_favoriteMerchantInner">
            <MerchantExperienceLink
              className="mn_favoriteMerchantLink"
              merchant={merchant}
              title={`Opens merchant detail page at ${name}`}
            >
              <FavoriteIcon
                merchantId={id}
                merchantName={name}
                labelUnfavorite={`Remove ${name} from Favorites list`}
                showSpinner={!isFavorited}
              />
              <div className="mn_logo mn_noRebateMerchantLogo">
                <img data-test="favorited-merchant-logo" src={logoUrls._120x60} alt={name} />
              </div>
              {rebate && (
                <div className="mn_rebate mn_deactivatedRebate">
                {
                 showRebate
                  ? <MerchantNoRebateLabel />
                  : <MerchantRebate {...rebate} />
                }
                </div>
              )}
            </MerchantExperienceLink>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
}
}

const mapStateToProps = () => {
  const selectFavoriteByMerchantId = makeSelectFavoriteByMerchantId();
  return (state, { merchant }) => ({
    isFavorited: selectFavoriteByMerchantId(state, merchant.id),
 });
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(FavoritesListItemDeactivatedMerchant);
```

Project builded without errors and also no errors in console. But it's not render this component in browser. What I'm doing wrong? Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

You have confused the syntax for function and class components and created a weird mash-up that combines both:

```
export class FavoritesListItemDeactivatedMerchant extends Component ({ merchant, config, isFavorited }) {
```

Those props make no sense in a class!  I think you meant to write this:

```
export const FavoritesListItemDeactivatedMerchant = ({ merchant, config, isFavorited }) => {
```

or

```
export function FavoritesListItemDeactivatedMerchant({ merchant, config, isFavorited }) {
```

Personally I think you can improve this code by having a shared `RenderMerchant` with a prop `isDeactivated` instead of having separate components for active and deactivated.  There is a lot of repeated code between the two cases which you want to avoid.